# Creating a stacked and grouped bar chart in pandas

Tags: matplotlib, pandas

I have a multi-indexed pandas dataframe and want to create a bar-chart where I group by one index and stack over the other.
Currently I do this very manually using matplotlib. This looks like a common task. Can I achieve this in pandas somehow?
[image: example image]